# Find E[X] and V[X]

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, variance

Let the random variable X satisfy $$E\left[(X −1)^2\right] = 10$$ and $$E\left[(X −2)^2\right] = 6.$$

No clue how to start this one... To find E[X] do I integrate both?
Would appreciate some hints on how to start this one.

Kinda lost on how to start this one since I never encountered this problem before.

Comment: Hint: Use 'Linearity of Expectation'

Comment: @Rocca If my answer covered your question, please mark it as correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have
\begin{eqnarray}
E[(X-1)^2]=10&\Rightarrow&E[X^2-2X+1]=10\nonumber\\
&\Rightarrow&E[X^2]-2E[X]+1=10\nonumber\\
&\Rightarrow&E[X^2]-2E[X]=9\nonumber\qquad(1)
\end{eqnarray}

\begin{eqnarray}
E[(X-2)^2]=6&\Rightarrow&E[X^2-4X+4]=6\nonumber\\
&\Rightarrow&E[X^2]-4E[X]+4=6\nonumber\\
&\Rightarrow&E[X^2]-4E[X]=2\nonumber\qquad(2)
\end{eqnarray}

Subtract (2) from (1) to get 
$$E[X]=\frac{7}{2}$$

By (2)
$$E[X^2]=16$$

Then 
$$Var(X)=E[X^2]-(E[X])^2=16-\frac{49}{4}$$

Comment: It is generally better from a number of points of view to not give complete answers, but rather hints, when the OP has no clue how to start and the question is undergrad level.

Comment: Thanks. It helped me to understand what it was I needed to do! @mgus

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $E$ is a linear map. But to use this fact, you need the input to be a *sum* of random variables... can you turn a square into a sum somehow?